# Blank page error due to location pathname

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As titled,

I've a webpage which has multiple pages on it. The page was originally a single page app created using jQuery before I moved some of the contents into separate files, and load it dynamically using a jQuery templating plugin. The page starts at default `pathname` ('/') and whenever the content change, the `pathname` on the URL will change too.

```
function goTo(page){
    // Changing URL without reloading the page (to allow changing the URL 
   //state without changing the page)
    if (page !== 'main'){
        console.log("Yes it is not main!");
        window.history.pushState("", "", "/"+page);
    } else {
        console.log("Yes it is main!");
        window.history.pushState("", "", "/");
    }

    // Set page template
    $('#main').loadTemplate('pages/'+page+'.html');
}
```

The above is the method i used to change the URL and content whenever user clicks on the link.

The problem that I encounter is that, whenever I refresh the page when there is a pathname on the URL, the page will return 404 error (not found) and it will return an unknown blank html page that is totally empty (no css and script loaded).

For example, the main page URL is http://localhost:8000, and if I clicked to page A, the URL becomes http://localhost:8000/pageA. However in pageA, when I refresh the page, it will return blank. Only if I reset the URL to http://localhost:8000 then the page will refresh normally.

Is there a way to fix this blank page and `pathname` problem? Like changed the `pathname` before the DOM loads?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Using `window.history.pushState` you will replace the browser location, and by hit page refresh you are sending request to the server, and you are asking to serve the page which name is in the location bar. However the page does not exist on the server so the server answers with Not found and that's correct behavior.

You have two options:

1. Implement the page also on the server side
2. Use client routing using hash (there are a lot of libraries for that, for example http://projects.jga.me/routie/)